# convert List<List<Integer>> to 2D char array?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a `List<List<Integer>> arr` which is `2D_INTEGER_ARRAY`. I need to convert this to 2D `char[][]` array. I tried with below code but it is giving compilation issue which is obvious but not able to figure out how can I do that?

```
   public static int largestMatrix(List<List<Integer>> arr) {
    char[][] matrix = new char[arr.size()][];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        List<Integer> row = arr.get(i);
        // below line is giving error
        matrix[i] = row.toArray(new char[row.size()]);
    }
   }
```

Error is:

```
[Java] The method toArray(T[]) in the type List<Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (char[])
```

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: updated the question..

Comment: Try `new Character[row.size()]`. `char` is a primitive type and is incompatible with generics. Although the issue may also be with the attempted implicit casting from `Integer` to `Character`. Not sure which one it is.

Comment: Now it says - "incompatible types".  Error is: `error: incompatible types
            matrix[i] = row.toArray(new Character[row.size()]);
                                   ^
  required: char[]
  found:    Character[]`

Comment: Well, define `matrix` as a `Character[][]` instead of `char[][]` too, of course.

Comment: Are the integers digits or ascii codes?

Comment: they are digits..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Integer` and `char` are separate types. If you want an integer represented as a digit, you need to convert it (casting will only give you the ASCII representation). Besides, you can't call `toArray()` with a primitive array. You'll have to iterate and convert manually:

```
matrix[i] = new char[row.size()];
for (int j = 0; j < row.size(); j++) {
    matrix[i][j] = Character.forDigit(row.get(j), 10);
}
```

Comment: what is row here? sorry got confuse

Comment: That's your variable, inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you are trying to convert `List<Integer>` to `char[]` in this line:

```
matrix[i] = row.toArray(new char[row.size()]);
```

You can do so using this:

```
matrix[i] = row.stream()
        .map(j -> Integer.toString(j))
        .collect(Collectors.joining())
        .toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do it purely using java-8 streams as follows, I have taken a cue from [Kartik's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54642412/3888766) answer on the conversion of Stream of `Integer` to Stream of `char[]`:

```
List<List<Integer>> list = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(1,2,3), Arrays.asList(4,5,6), Arrays.asList(7,8,9));
char[][] chars = list.stream().map(l -> l.stream()
                                         .map( i-> Integer.toString(i))
                                         .collect(Collectors.joining())
                                         .toCharArray())
                              .toArray(char[][]::new);
```